# Assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast warning

Tags: c, pointers

I can see this has been asked countless times but I couldn't quite relate the answers I found my individual situation. I'm still getting the hang of C and haven't quite got my head around pointers yet. A basic version of the code I'm having issue with is below:

```
int function(unsigned long *timestamp)
{
     timestamp = GetTick();
}
```

Where the `GetTick()` function returns a value of type `uint32_t`.

My problem then is that I get a compiler warning that the assignment makes a pointer from an integer without a cast. I understand that pointers and variables are different but I don't fully understand what the meaning of the warning is nor the right way to make the assignment? Any suggestions?

Edit: Might be worth mentioning that I didn't write this code myself, I'm simply trying to port it to use a new set of drivers that should allow it to do the same thing, in theory.

---

Update:

A cleaner version of the above code:

```
int function(unsigned long *timestamp)
{
     if (timestamp)
         timestamp = GetTick();
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: unsigned int and uint32_t are different types. Your argument to the function should probably be uint32_t timestamp. Or you should cast the return value of GetTick(). Also note that timestamp is a pointer (see answers).

Comment: @brauner: It is perhaps a good idea to prefix a comment which will not actually solve the problem, but improve the code (or correct a minor flaw) with "Note" or similar. About `uint32_t` I agree, however.

Comment: Is there any reason to pass apointer and not just return the value (whatever it is wort to wrap a function in another function for your project). Note that you do not return a result; if your compiler does not complain, enable warnings (at least `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion` for gcc) and compiler in C11 or at least C99 mode.

Comment: There is still the problem with GetTick() returning an int while timestamp is a pointer. But that is, as I said, covered in the answers.

Comment: @brauner: "*you should cast*" why, please?

Comment: @Olaf, I agree. Sorry.

Comment: @alk, not necessary or needed, I agree, since the cast is performed implicitly and uint32_t will hold an int as long as it is max. 32bit.

Comment: @brauner @Olaf, Perhaps a bad example of the code. I stripped it back to try make it as simple as possible. I've updated a bit to try reflect what is happening in `function`. I'm fairly new to C and I've been tasked with porting a pretty sizeable codebase. It's been a bit of an uphill struggle. Thanks for the input guys.

Comment: It's not a good idea to change a question, after comments/answers had been posted already, as those changes might makes the comments/answers ununderstandable. I modifyed your answer to follow this guideline.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My problem then is that I get a compiler warning that the assignment makes a pointer to an integer

No, the warning is saying the opposite: you're making an integer into a pointer. That's because `GetTick` returns an integer but you're assigning the result to `timestamp`, which is a pointer. You probably meant:

```
    *timestamp = GetTick();
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use:

```
*timestamp = GetTick();
```

as you have passed pointer and you need to set the value at the memory address pointed to by the pointer.

Answer (score 2):

`timestamp` is a pointer, `GetTick()` returns a value.
You should do

```
int function(unsigned long *timestamp)
{
     *timestamp = GetTick();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

a pointer is just an address `unsigned long *timestamp= NULL`. To get the underlying value stored at that address you must de-reference the pointer `*timestamp`. since you are passing in a pointer to the function if you want to assign a value you must use, in this case, `*timestamp = GetTick();`

In addition, `if(timestamp)` will be checking the pointer address. if you want it to check if there is an existing value within the pointer you again need to de-reference, `if(*timestamp)`

Comment: `if(*timestamp)` test for `0`, which also is a value.